# DebugVisualizer, circular reference

Tags: c#, debugging, reference, visualizer

The problem I'm facing might be stupid, but I've never encountered it, so I guess I need some help. I'm learning how to use a Debug Visualizer. 
I've created one: `DebuggerSide.cs` located in `CarGarageVisualizer` namespace.

I wanted the type of `CarGarage<T>` to be seen in this visualizer when debugging instance of this, so I've put following attributes to the class:

```
    [DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(CarGarageVisualizer.DebuggerSide))]
    [Serializable]
    public class CarGarage<T>:IEnumerable<T>
        where T : Car,new()
    {
    ...
    }
```

Now, to add first attribute I needed to add reference to `CarGarageVisualizer` that contains the `DebuggerSide` class. That's OK. But now, in my `DebuggerSide`'s overriden method `Show()` I wanted to explicitly cast object gained from the `objectProvider` argument to the type of `CarGarage<T>`. But to be able to do this I would need to reference the `CarGarageLibrary` that contains the definition of this. And as I said I can't do that, because I get the error about recursive reference.

From other post on this subject, I know it's a bad practice. But, I don't want to copy the `CarGarage<T>` class to my Visualizer namespace (that would solve the problem, but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do) unless there's not a better option.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You should put the `CarGarageVisualizer.DebuggerSide` in a separate library that will and can be referenced by both.</s>

Didn't get it correctly, I think.

What about, putting the `CarGarage<T>` in a separate library.

```
library CarGarage:
[Serializable]
public class CarGarage<T>:IEnumerable<T>
    where T : Car,new()
{
...
}
```

---

```
library DebugVis:  (uses CarGarage)
DebuggerSide....
```

---

```
library app:  (uses CarGarage)
[DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(CarGarageVisualizer.DebuggerSide))]
public class CarGarageImpl<T> : CarGarage<T> { }
```

Comment: I don't get the sense of it. I've used the template to create the Debug Visualizer and now I need to put it to another library? That seems just stupid.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to accept:) Ofc that was the correct answer, it should be kept in a separate library, I messed up on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DebuggerVisualizerAttribute` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140795(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes `string` containing the [fully qualified type name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx) of the visualizer like this

```
public static class MyVisualizers
{
    public const string AssemblyRef = @"MyVisualizers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
}

[DebuggerVisualizer("MyVisualizersNamespace.CarGarageVisualizer+DebuggerSide, " + MyVisualizers.AssemblyRef)]
[Serializable]
public class CarGarage<T>:IEnumerable<T>
    where T : Car,new()
{
    ...
}
```